# Do I have to run ssh-agent everytime I push/pull to/from BitBucket from my server to store the passphrase?

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, cpanel, whm

At the moment, everytime I log into my cPanel server via SSH I have to start ssh-agent and store the passphrase for use only for that session, is there a way for me to store it indefinitely like I can in my Keychain on OSX?

I've looked around on a few forums and it almost seems like that it isn't possible? Could anyone point me in the right direction if this is a possibility?

**EDIT:**
I tried to use an empty passphrase in the cPanel SSH key generator but it doesn't allow me to do that.
[image: SSH key empty passphrase]

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[How to use Mac OS X Keychain with SSH keys?](https://superuser.com/a/88584/141)" the whole point of the keychain is to store the passphrase to your ssh keys.

But you still need to [load your ssh keys in the ssh agent](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html).

> The OSX 10.6.8 system asks for your connection parameters the first time you try to establish a SSH connection.
>   Then, it automatically starts the ssh-agent for you

That helps [to connect to cPanel](https://fr.godaddy.com/help/connect-to-your-server-or-shared-hosting-account-with-ssh-4943), but once you are in the cPanel server, it is best to use a different ssh key, without passphrase, to access your BitButcket repo.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but is there a way to use something similar to the OSX Keychain on a cPanel server?

Comment: @thePav Then from cPanel, you should use a different passphrase-less ssh key.I have edited the answer to indicate as much.

Comment: Let's just focus on my cPanel/WHM server, forget about the OSX machine.
I have an SSH key that I have generated on the cPanel server, I have added the public key to BitBucket and I have cloned the git repository.
cPanel does not allow me to generate an SSH Key with an empty passphrase (I have updated my question with a screenshot).

Comment: @thePav Then generate an ssh key (without passphrase)  outside of the cPanel, and copy it (scp) to the cPanel server)

Comment: Ok, I will try that - though is there no way to achieve this without having to have an empty passphrase?

Comment: @thePav I don't know one, hence this workaround. The idea is to have a different dedicated key for BitBucket access from cPanel server.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like ask for passphrase, must be create ssh key on shell (SSH). Cpanel create all time, keys with passphrase.

For access to Cpanel if you don't `~/.ssh/id_rsa` keys on your mac Box.

- Open terminal
- create your key with `ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -b 4096` and when ask for passphrase, click enter (not passphrase)
- After this your keys are on ~/.ssh/ (id_rsa & id_rsa.pub)

If have a `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
Now two ways.

Cpanel way:

- Go to **SSH Access -> Manage  SSH Keys -> Import key**
- Put a descrptive name on **Choose a name for this key (defaults to id_dsa):**
- Intro on **Paste the public key into the following text box:** content of  `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- Click **Import**
- Return to  **Manage  SSH Keys**
- Click om **Managed** and **Authorized**

Know you can access to your Cpanel account without password.

SSH Way quickly:

- On your mac box: `ssh-copy-id user@just.some.other.server`

SSH Way extended:

- On your mac `cat  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- Copy content
- Access to your cpanel account
- echo 'CONTENT_OF_~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub' >> .ssh/authorized_keys